# SharePoint 2013 Mandatory Column when Based on drop down on another column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, calculated-column-formula, validation

I have a SharePoint 2013 list where I need to log Issues.

One of my column is labelled "Issue Status". Generally, I have REQUIRED field populated when the form is filed out and the "Issue Status" = OPEN or = PENDING.

But I want to make some columns REQUIRED and others OPTIONAL when someone selects "Issue Status" = DRAFT.

Can this is done by Validation Setting in SharePoint? If so, what is the formula?

For example: IF "Issue Status" = DRAFT then "Control ID" and "Impacted Business" Column is OPTIONAL and the rest is REQUIRED.

All I want is when someone logs an issue as a draft they have a freedom not to fill all the required columns. For example, when an issue is saved as a draft they will fill only TWO of the required column but if the issue is set to "Open" they will fill ALL the required column

Comment: How many "rest" columns you have in your list which you want to make optional while drafting the issue?

Comment: yes. so i want "Issue Owner", Issue Coordinator" , "Exposure Type" and "Issue Severity" all optional.

Comment: Can you confirm again? In you question, you said when status is DRAFT, you want to make "Control ID" and "Impacted Business" as optional & other columns as required (those are required for all status values/choices), right?

Comment: So I have list COLUMN-Issue Status, Control ID, Impacted Business, Issue Owner, Issue Coordinator, Issue Severity and Exposure Type. These have drop down options. All the columns are set to required when filing the form. But When I select "Issue Status =Draft" (in Drop down option) I want only  Control ID" and "Impacted Business" as optional column and the rest ( Issue Owner, Issue Coordinator, Issue Severity and Exposure Type) to be required. This rule is only true when the Issue status is "Draft. For Issue status "Open" everything should be required.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this approach:

1. Make "Control ID" and "Impacted Business" as optional columns & all other columns as required from list settings.
2. Use below formula in list validation settings from **List settings** >> **Validation settings**.

```
=IF(NOT([Issue Status] = "DRAFT"), IF(OR(ISBLANK([Control ID]), ISBLANK([Impacted Business])), false, true), true)
```

**Note**:

Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

Comment: I got error message when putting this formula. It says "The formula Contains a syntax error or is not supported"

Comment: Where are you adding this formula? In column validation settings or list validation settings (use this)? Also, use correct display names of your actual columns in formula.

Comment: list validation setting

Comment: i copied pasted the exact formula but it error out

Comment: Check if your column names & column names in my formula are exact same. if not, use your column names instead.

Comment: Its exactly the same